# Django-skel slow due to httplib requests to S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

G'day,

I am playing around with `django-skel` on a recent project and have used most of its defaults: `Heroku` for hosting and `S3` for file storage. I'm mostly serving a static-y site except using `sorl` for thumbnail generation, however the response times are pathetic.

You can visit the site: http://bit.ly/XlzkXp

My template looks like: https://gist.github.com/cd15e320be6f4454a7fb

I'm serving the template using a shortcut from the URL conf, no database usage at all: https://gist.github.com/f9d1a9a191959dcff1b5

However, it's consistently taking 15+ seconds for the response. New relic shows this is because of requests going to S3 while processing the view. This does not make any sense to me.

New Relic data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6udai.png

Why is something using `httplib` to request things from S3? I can see how collectstatic might be doing it, but not the processing of the view itself.

What am I not understanding about Django-skel and this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, my guess is that:

- django-compress with django-storage are both in use
- which results the former saving cache it needs to render templates to S3 bucket
- and then reading it (through network, so httplib) while rendering each template

My second guess was that instructions on [django-compress with remote storage](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote-storages/#using-staticfiles) to implement "*S3 Storage backend which caches files locally, too*" would resolve this issue.

Though it makes sense to me: saving cache to both locations local and S3 and reading from local filesystem first should speed things up, it somehow **does not** work this way..  still the response time is around 8+ sec.

By disabling django-compress with `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False` i managed to get 1-1.3 sec average response time.

Any ideas?
*(I will update this answer in case of any progress)*